# How do I use Jquery to select multiple forms and their children and alert their values?

Tags: jquery, children

This is how far I've gotten:

```
  $('form').each(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).children('input.required').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val())
      })
    })
  })
```

The event.preventDefault() is working because the form doesn't submit. But after that it won't do anything. I tried this

```
alert($(this).attr('id'))
```

right under

```
$(this).submit(function() {
```

and it worked too, it alerted the correct form id when I clicked submit. But for some reason I just can't get the children to work. After some reading I also tried

```
 $('form').each(function(index,element) {
    $(element).submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault()
      $(element).children('.required').each(function(ind,ele) {
        alert($(ele).val())
      })
    })
  })
```

but that didn't work either.

I need to select specific inputs with the "required" class to check their value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that your `input` elements are not child nodes of the `form` but descendant nodes. That is to say, there are other nodes in the tree between the `form` and the `input`, perhaps `table` or `p` elements.

You should use `find` instead:

```
$(element).find('.required').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This finds all descendant nodes matching a selector, not just direct children.

Comment: Thanks, that was right. But I can't specify 'input.required'. Why not?

Comment: @Matthew You should be able to... Just do `find('input.required')`.

Comment: I tried that. It was the only thing I changed and it wouldn't work, but I found a work around. I'm selecting input and then a hasClass after that